Close Video call and still running camera !!! (Flutter WebRTC)
Hello Flutter Community:
i am using flutter_webrtc package to add video call feature to my app, it is working fine but when try to close the video call , still camera running in the background.
I am using this class to manage the whole process
class CallVideoEntity {
  RTCVideoRenderer? localRenderer;
  RTCVideoRenderer? remoteRenderer;
  RTCPeerConnection? peerConnection;
  MediaStream? localStream;
  bool offer = false;
  bool isNotificationCallOn = false;
  bool isOpenCallVideoScreen = false;
  SDPEntity? sdpOfferEntity;
  SDPEntity? sdpAnswerEntity;
  ChatEntity? chatEntity;
  CandidateEntity? candidateMemberEntity;
  CandidateEntity? candidateUserEntity;
  BlocChangerCubit callVideoCubit = BlocChangerCubit();
  Socket socket = io(
      DataHelper.wsUrl, OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());

  dispose() async {
    print('cancel video call start');
    localRenderer!.srcObject = null;
    remoteRenderer!.srcObject = null;
    await peerConnection!.close();
    await peerConnection!.removeStream(localStream!);
    await peerConnection!.dispose();
    await localRenderer!.dispose();
    await remoteRenderer!.dispose();

    localRenderer = null;
    remoteRenderer = null;
    peerConnection = null;
    localStream = null;
    sdpOfferEntity = null;
    sdpAnswerEntity = null;
    candidateUserEntity = null;
    candidateMemberEntity = null;
    chatEntity = null;
    offer = false;
    isNotificationCallOn = false;
    isOpenCallVideoScreen = false;
    print('cancel video call end');
  }

  initRenderer(Function updateFunction) async {
    localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
    remoteRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
    await localRenderer!.initialize();
    await remoteRenderer!.initialize();

    isNotificationCallOn = true;
    isOpenCallVideoScreen = true;

    _createPeerConnectionData().then((pc) async {
      peerConnection = pc;

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
      callVideoCubit.update();

      if (offer) {
        //!
        await createOffer();
      } else {
        await setRemoteDescription();
        await createAnswer();
      }

      // socket.on('leaveVideo', (data) {
      //   if (isOpenCallVideoScreen) {
      //     print('tesssst');
      //     isNotificationCallOn = false;
      //     RouteGenerator.routerClient.pop();
      //   }
      // });
    });
  }

  _createPeerConnectionData() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
      "sdpSemantics": "plan-b",
      "iceServers": [
        {"url": 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
        {"url": 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
        {"url": 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
        {"url": 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
        {"url": 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
      ]
    };

    final Map<String, dynamic> offerSdpConstraints = {
      "mandatory": {
        "OfferToReceiveAudio": true,
        "OfferToReceiveVideo": true,
      },
      "optional": [],
    };

    localStream = await _getUserMedia();

    RTCPeerConnection pc =
        await createPeerConnection(configuration, offerSdpConstraints);

    pc.addStream(localStream!);

    pc.onIceCandidate = (e) {
      candidateMemberEntity ??= CandidateEntity(
          userSeries: 'user-1', // !chatEntity!.userSeries
          memberSeries: DataHelper.currentUser == null
              ? ''
              : DataHelper.currentUser!.series,
          type: "candicate",
          data: CandidateData(
              candidate: e.candidate ?? '',
              sdpMLineIndex: e.sdpMLineIndex ?? 0,
              sdpMid: e.sdpMid ?? '0',
              usernameFragment: '5d94bba3'));
      print('tesssCandidate:${candidateMemberEntity != null}');
    };

    pc.onIceConnectionState = (e) {
      // print(e);
    };

    pc.onAddStream = (stream) {
      // print('addStream: ' + stream.id);
      remoteRenderer!.srcObject = stream;
    };

    return pc;
  }

  _getUserMedia() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> constraints = {
      'audio': true,
      // 'video': true
      'video': {
        'facingMode': 'user',
      },
    };

    MediaStream stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

    localRenderer!.srcObject = stream;
    // _localRenderer.mirror = true;

    return stream;
  }

  Future<void> createOffer() async {
    RTCSessionDescription description =
        await peerConnection!.createOffer({'offerToReceiveVideo': 1});

    var session = description.sdp.toString();

    peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(description);

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    SDPEntity answerSDP = SDPEntity(
        memberSeries: DataHelper.currentUser == null
            ? ''
            : DataHelper.currentUser!.series,
        userSeries: 'user-1', //! chatEntity!.userSeries
        type: "sdp",
        data: SDPData(sdp: session, type: "offer"));
    socket.emit('rtc', answerSDP.toJson());

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    CandidateEntity candidateDataEntity = CandidateEntity(
        userSeries: sdpOfferEntity == null ? '' : sdpOfferEntity!.userSeries,
        memberSeries: DataHelper.currentUser == null
            ? ''
            : DataHelper.currentUser!.series,
        type: "candicate",
        data: CandidateData(
            candidate: candidateMemberEntity!.data.candidate,
            sdpMid: candidateMemberEntity!.data.sdpMid,
            sdpMLineIndex: candidateMemberEntity!.data.sdpMLineIndex,
            usernameFragment: "5d94bba3"));
    socket.emit('rtc', candidateDataEntity.toJson());
  }

  Future<void> createAnswer() async {
    RTCSessionDescription description =
        await peerConnection!.createAnswer({'offerToReceiveVideo': 1});

    var session = description.sdp.toString();
    print('test_SDP_${session}');
    peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(description);

    SDPEntity answerSDP = SDPEntity(
        memberSeries: DataHelper.currentUser == null
            ? ''
            : DataHelper.currentUser!.series,
        userSeries: sdpAnswerEntity == null ? "" : sdpAnswerEntity!.userSeries,
        type: "sdp",
        data: SDPData(sdp: session, type: "answer"));
    socket.emit('rtc', answerSDP.toJson());

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 4500));
    CandidateEntity candidateDataEntity = CandidateEntity(
        userSeries: sdpAnswerEntity!.userSeries,
        memberSeries: DataHelper.currentUser == null
            ? ''
            : DataHelper.currentUser!.series,
        type: "candicate",
        data: CandidateData(
            candidate: candidateMemberEntity!.data.candidate,
            sdpMid: candidateMemberEntity!.data.sdpMid,
            sdpMLineIndex: candidateMemberEntity!.data.sdpMLineIndex,
            usernameFragment: "5d94bba3"));
    socket.emit('rtc', candidateDataEntity.toJson());

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
    callVideoCubit.update();
  }

  Future<void> setRemoteDescription() async {
    print('Offer? :${offer}');
    String jsonString =
        offer ? sdpOfferEntity!.data.sdp : sdpAnswerEntity!.data.sdp;

    String sdp = write(parse(jsonString), null);
    print('sdp? :${sdp}');

    RTCSessionDescription description =
        RTCSessionDescription(sdp, offer ? 'answer' : 'offer');
    print('description? :${description.toMap()}');

    await peerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(description);

    if (offer) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
      await addCandidate();
    }
  }

  addCandidate() async {
    //String jsonString = candidateUserEntity!.toJson().toString();

    dynamic candidate = RTCIceCandidate(
        candidateUserEntity!.data.candidate,
        candidateUserEntity!.data.sdpMid,
        candidateUserEntity!.data.sdpMLineIndex);
    await peerConnection!.addCandidate(candidate);
    callVideoCubit.update();
  }
}

for ui i am using this code :
class VideoCallPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoCallPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _VideoCallPageState();
}

class _VideoCallPageState extends State<VideoCallPage> {
  bool _isAudioMuted = false;
  bool _showButtons = false;
  bool _isVideoMuted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WakelockPlus.enable();
    DataHelper.callVideoEntity.initRenderer(() => setState(() {}));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    DataHelper.callVideoEntity.dispose();
    WakelockPlus.disable();
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: BlocChangerBuilder(
          cubit: DataHelper.callVideoEntity.callVideoCubit,
          builder: (context, state) => Stack(
            children: [
              //////////////////// * User Screen * ///////////////////
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Container(
                    key: const Key("remote"),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black54),
                    child: RTCVideoView(
                        DataHelper.callVideoEntity.remoteRenderer!)),
              ),

              //////////////////// * Member Screen * ///////////////////
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 147,
                    height: 260,
                    child: Container(
                        key: const Key("local"),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                        child: RTCVideoView(
                          DataHelper.callVideoEntity.localRenderer!,
                          filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              //////////////////// * Buttons * ///////////////////
              AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: _showButtons ? 1 : 0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                child: AnimatedSlide(
                  offset:
                      _showButtons ? const Offset(0, 0) : const Offset(-20, 0),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.black87, Colors.transparent],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      )),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          MaterialButton(
                            color: DataHelper.getCurrentColor(),
                            shape: const CircleBorder(),
                            onPressed: _toggleAudioMute,
                            child: _isAudioMuted
                                ? const Icon(
                                    Icons.mic_off,
                                    size: 23,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                : const Icon(Icons.mic,
                                    color: Colors.white, size: 23),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 6,
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                            color: DataHelper.getCurrentColor(),
                            shape: const CircleBorder(),
                            onPressed: _toggleVideoMute,
                            child: _isVideoMuted
                                ? const Icon(
                                    Icons.videocam_off,
                                    size: 23,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                : const Icon(
                                    Icons.videocam,
                                    size: 23,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 6,
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                              color: DataHelper.getCurrentColor(),
                              shape: const CircleBorder(),
                              onPressed: () {
                                DataHelper.callVideoEntity
                                    .isNotificationCallOn = false;
                                DataHelper.callVideoEntity
                                    .isOpenCallVideoScreen = false;

                                SDPEntity sdp = SDPEntity(
                                    memberSeries: DataHelper.currentUser == null
                                        ? ''
                                        : DataHelper.currentUser!.series,
                                    userSeries:
                                        'user-1', //! chatEntity!.userSeries
                                    type: "leaveVideo",
                                    data: SDPData(sdp: '', type: "leaveVideo"));
                                DataHelper.callVideoEntity.socket
                                    .emit('rtc', sdp.toJson());
                                // context.pop();
                                RouteGenerator.routerClient.pop();
                              },
                              child: const Icon(
                                Icons.close,
                                size: 23,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              //////////////////// * Clicker * ///////////////////
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: IconButton(
                  color: DataHelper.getCurrentColor(),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _showButtons = !_showButtons;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.movie_rounded,
                    size: 28,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleAudioMute() {
    if (DataHelper.callVideoEntity.localStream != null) {
      DataHelper.callVideoEntity.localStream!.getAudioTracks().forEach((track) {
        track.enabled = _isAudioMuted;
      });

      setState(() {
        _isAudioMuted = !_isAudioMuted;
      });
    }
  }

  void _toggleVideoMute() {
    if (DataHelper.callVideoEntity.localStream != null) {
      DataHelper.callVideoEntity.localStream!.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) {
        track.enabled = _isVideoMuted;
      });

      setState(() {
        _isVideoMuted = !_isVideoMuted;
      });
    }
  }
}


You can see that I dispose the video call completely when I hang up,
Then I see in my log this message repeated several times

I/org.webrtc.Logging(18069): CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.

thanks for your help ❤
Try closing the video call completely with the camera still running in the background!


You can see that I dispose the video call completely when I hang up

You do, but you never close tracks of the stream acquired by getUserMedia which means the camera is still on. Try iterating over the localRenderers stream and stopping each track like this:
localRenderer!.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())

before localRenderer!.srcObject = null;
